# Help with using TypeConverters for enums in an Excel PIA assembly

Tags: .net, excel, pia

I would like to use a TypeCoverter to regionalise output for enums in an assembly that is a PIA loaded into Excel.

I can run this and it works on an assembly in a test project I created with an explicitly referenceed assembly, however when running a project that has been built as an Excel PIA.  If I try:
 _
public enum MyEnum
    ItemA
    ItemB
end enum

and in code
myE = MyEnum.ItemA
Dim converter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(myE)

In the immediate window
? converter.ToString() goves 
"System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter"

whereas in my other project (also a strongly signed assembly, but referenced directly from a newly created stub windows form project), I get

? converter.ToString
"ClassLibrary1.LocalizedEnumConverter"

so it look like the LocalizedEnumConverter is not being bound to the enum - any ideas?  Is this because of the way Excel loads the assembly, and is there a way arounfd this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of digging around, I have found the solution, this will work for an assembly that is loaded by cannot be resolved:

Add a handler for the Assembly Resolution:

```
    Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    AddHandler currentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf AssemblyResolve_EventHandler
```

then to handle the resolution:

```
Private Function AssemblyResolve_EventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ResolveEventArgs) As System.Reflection.Assembly
    Dim asm() As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

    For i As Integer = 0 To asm.Length
        If asm(i).FullName = e.Name Then
            Return asm(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the type converter in the same dll as the enum? TypeDescriptor must be able to resolve the type-converters, UI-type-editors, etc - otherwise it uses the simple defaults.

I haven't tried anything sepcifically with Excel, but I'm wondering if it isn't as simple as assembly resolution...

If it helps, you can use the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to customize assembly loading - but this is a complex area... I'd avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: The type converter is in the same dll, My suspicion is that it is probably down to the way Excel / (Office) loads PIAs.